# Duplicate entry IMG002 for key PRIMARY

Tags: php, mysql

Help me to resolve this issue, Duplicate entry 'IMG002' for key 'PRIMARY'.

IMG002 only stored in the database and IMG001 not in the database. and results of .$hasilkode always IMG002.

```
$carikode = mysql_query("select * from foto") or die (mysql_error());
  $datakode = mysql_fetch_array($carikode);
  $jumlah_data = mysql_num_rows($carikode);
  if ($datakode) {
   $nilaikode = substr($jumlah_data[0], 1);
   $kode = (int) $nilaikode;
   $kode = $jumlah_data + 1;
   $hasilkode = "IMG".str_pad($kode, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
  } else {
   $hasilkode = "IMG001";
  }
$sql = "INSERT INTO foto (id,gambar,keterangan) values ('$hasilkode','$fileName','".$_POST['kete']."')";
mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means you've got what appears to be the 'id' column in your database set as a primary key (i.e. - unique) and you're apparently attempting to create rows with duplicate values (in this case 'IMG002').

Comment: the previous contents of the table there is no data. after I saved, stored inside the table IMG002 and not IMG001

Comment: I have overcome the problem. I just change, "select max(id) from foto" to "select * from foto"

Answer (score 0):

Primary keys must contain **UNIQUE** values, and **cannot contain NULL** values.

You have need to check first **hasilkode** exist or not in db **if exist** then execute **update query** otherwise execute **insert query**

Other way is you can add new column for store **hasilkode** and set **auto increment to id column** then execute insert query.

Comment: add new column for store value hasilkode

Comment: I have overcome the problem. I just change, "select max(id) from foto" to "select * from foto"